# Is the image of a nowhere dense closed subset of $[0,1]$ under a differentiable map still nowhere dense?

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology

Let $f:[0,1]\to[0,1]$ be a continuous function such that its derivative $f'$ exists on $(0,1)$. My question is:

> **Q1.** If $E\subset[0,1]$ is a nowhere dense closed subset, is $f(E)$ also nowhere dense in $[0,1]$?

If the answer is negative, what will happen when we additionaly assume that $f'\ge 0$ on $(0,1)$?

My question originates from the follow question:

> **Q2.** If $g:[0,1]\to[0,1]$ is the [Cantor function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cantor_function), can we find
> homeomorphisms $\varphi$ and $\psi$ both from $[0,1]$ to itself, such
> that $\psi\circ g\circ \varphi$ is differntiable on $(0,1)$?

If **Q1** with the addtional assumption $f'\ge 0$ has a positive answer, then clearly it gives a negative answer to the second question, because for any $\varphi$ and $\psi$, $f=\psi\circ g\circ \varphi$ maps a nowhere dense closed set onto $[0,1]$. Otherwise, I am still interested in whether $\varphi$ and $\psi$ exist or not. **Q2** comes from an attempt in providing a simple counter-example to [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/412791/46120) for the case $X=Y=(0,1)$.

---

**Update**:

1. Thanks to Henno Brandsma's comment below, I realized to add a remark that **Q1** has a positive answer when $f$ is (piecewise) $C^1$.
2. Thanks to the discussion with Jim Belk, I realized that my original argument on  **Q1** under the assumption that $f$ is $C^1$ was incorrect. The following is a corrected argument.

   Denote the Lebesgue measure on $[0,1]$ by $|\cdot|$ and denote $C=\{x\in[0,1]:f'(x)=0\}$. Note that $C$ is a closed. Using the fact that for every closed subset $K$ of $[0,1]$,
   $$|f(K)|\le\int_K|f'(x)|dx,$$
   or otherwise, we know that $f(C)$ is closed and $|f(C)|=0$, so $f(C)$, and hence $f(C\cap E)$, are closed and nowhere dense. Note that $[0,1]\setminus C$ is a disjoint union of at most countably many intervals, say $[0,1]\setminus C=\sqcup_n I_n$. Note that $f|_{\overline{I_n}}$ is homeomorphic, so $f(\overline{I_n}\cap E)$ is closed and nowhere dense. Then by Baire category theorem,
   $$f(E)=f(C\cap E)\cup\big(\cup_n f(\overline{I_n}\cap E)\big)$$
   is nowhere dense.
3. Moreover, I removed another question similar to **Q1** in this post, and  started [a new post](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/415759/46120) for it.

---

Any hint or suggestion is appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Note that you didn't have to assume the set is closed: if your conjecture holds for closed subsets, then it also holds for the rest: If $E$ is nowhere dense, then so is its closure, and clearly $f(E) \subseteq f(\bar E)$.

Comment: Also, in this context, a set is closed iff it is compact, so the image under a continuous function of a closed set is closed. So assuming $E$ is closed (WLOG, as my last comment shows), you can replace "nowhere dense" with "having empty interior" throughout.

Comment: @dfeuer: Of course you are right, but I think there is no essential difference between the two statements.

Comment: For $f$ a $C^1$ function there claims to be a proof at http://sci.tech-archive.net/Archive/sci.math.research/2005-02/0171.html (I haven't checked it myself).

Comment: @HennoBrandsma: I had already known that the $C^1$ case is correct, but I didn't realize that to point this fact out would be helpful for readers to this post. Thank you for reminding me of this!

Comment: A correction: The Baire category theorem does *not* assert that a countable union of nowhere dense sets is nowhere dense.  (Consider $\mathbb{Q}$ as a counterexample.)  All we can conclude from your argument using BCT is that $f(E) \ne [0,1]$

Comment: @NateEldredge: Here $E$ is closed and hence....

Comment: @Landscape: Oh, I got it.  Ok.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The answer to question Q1 is no.  The answer to question Q2 is yes, though it becomes no if we replace "differentiable" with "continuously differentiable".

The key reference is the following:

[Dovgoshey, O., et al. “The Cantor function.” *Expo. Math.* 24 (2006). 1–37](http://users.utu.fi/vuorinen/REA12/107.pdf)

The following theorem appears on pg. 25 of the paper (Proposition 7.5):

**Theorem 1.** *Let $g\colon[0,1]\to[0,1]$ be the Cantor function.  Then there exists a homeomorphism $\varphi\colon[0,1]\to[0,1]$ so that $g\circ\varphi$ is everywhere differentiable, with uniformly bounded derivative.*

Immediately afterwards (Proposition 7.6), it is proven that:

**Theorem 2.** *Let $g\colon[0,1]\to[0,1]$ be the Cantor function.  Then there do not exist homeomorphisms $\varphi,\psi\colon[0,1]\to[0,1]$ so that $\psi\circ g\circ\varphi$ is continuously differentiable.*

This settles question Q2.  Also, it follows from Theorem 1 that the answer to question Q1 is no.  In particular, if $C$ is the Cantor set, then $C$ is nowhere dense, so $\varphi^{-1}(C)$ is nowhere dense as well.  But the image of $\varphi^{-1}(C)$ under the differentiable function $g\circ\varphi$ is the same as $g(C)$, which is the entire unit interval $[0,1]$.

Of course, this does not address the question of whether the image of a nowhere dense set under a continuously differentiable function is always nowhere dense.  The post linked to by Henno is not entirely convincing, partially because I cannot follow the proof, but mostly because the author seems to retract the proof later in the thread:

- [Original post (linked to by Henno)](http://sci.tech-archive.net/Archive/sci.math.research/2005-02/0171.html)
- [Reply asking for a simpler proof](http://sci.tech-archive.net/Archive/sci.math.research/2005-02/0175.html)
- [Attempt at a simpler proof](http://sci.tech-archive.net/Archive/sci.math.research/2005-02/0181.html), by the same author, in which the author admits a mistake in the first proof.
- [The final post](http://sci.tech-archive.net/Archive/sci.math.research/2005-02/0177.html), in which the author seems to admit a mistake in the second proof as well, and claims that a counterexample exists. (This is my interpretation, but the post is very unclear.)

Though it's not entirely clear, the conclusion at the end of the thread seems to be that the answer to Q1 is no even in the $C^1$ case.  (**Edit:** As Landscape and George Lowther point out, there is indeed a simple argument that the answer to Q1 is yes for $C^1$ functions.)

Note that this answer does not conflict with [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/59105/is-the-image-of-a-null-set-under-a-differentiable-map-always-null), which states that the image of a set of measure zero under a differentiable function has measure zero.  Assuming the post is correct, the inverse image $\varphi^{-1}(C)$ of the Cantor set under the homeomorphism $\varphi$ must have positive Lebesgue measure.  This is of course possible for a nowhere dense set, e.g. the [fat Cantor set](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fat_Cantor_set).

Comment: Dear Jim Belk, thank you for your answer. I didn't read the argument in Henno's link carefully, but I think my argument in the question for the $C^1$ case is correct, isn't it?

Comment: Just for clarification, the discussion on Q1 in Henno's link is under the assumption that $f$ is $C^1$.

Comment: @Landscape That's an excellent point, I will edit my post to reflect this.

Comment: @Landscape  I'm trying to figure out what I think of the argument you give in the question for the $C^1$ case.  The main step I'm not sure about is the sentence starting with "For every".  Though $f$ is a local homeomorphism (and hence locally one-to-one) around $x$, it may be the case that multiple points in $E$ map to $f(x)$, so I don't see why $f(x)$ can't be an interior point of $f(E)$.

Comment: Yes, I agree with you. I made a stupid mistake. Thank you for pointing it out. I will edit my post later. By the way, do you think Q3 should be separated from this post?

Comment: @Landscape I think separating Q3 from this post is worthwhile.  I don't know the answer, and I'd be curious to see whether someone else could solve it.

Comment: @Landscape Also, note that I edited the end of my answer -- the results of my answer do not in fact conflict with the answer of George Lowther.

Comment: Dear Jim Belk, your answer looks perfect to me now! Please allow me not to reward the bounty until it expires, so that this post could draw more attention from others.

Comment: @Landscape Thanks!

Comment: You are welcome, but why thank me? I should thank you! :)

Comment: Very interesting, I was thinking about constructing an example for Q2, but it is rather tricky to say the least! I'll have to read the link in the answer.

Comment: And the $C^1$ case is easy isn't it? The domain breaks up into a countable number of intervals on which $f$ is a homeomorphism with its image, and where $f^\prime=0$ (which has closed image of zero measure). What's the issue with that argument? Note - it does use the Baire category theorem, which says that a countable union of nowhere dense closed sets is nowhere dense.

Comment: Dear @George Lowther, I edited my answer, and then found  you had already commented here. Moreover, the most embarrassing fact to me is that my correction is just the same as your comment.

Comment: @GeorgeLowther Ah, I see.  That does sound right then.  I had missed that you could take a countable subcover and then use the Baire Category Theorem.

Comment: @GeorgeLowther: But that's not what the Baire category theorem says!  (See also my comment on the question.)

Comment: @NateEldredge: Yes, you're right of course. The argument needs to be modified slightly. As $f$ is continuous, $f(E)$ is closed. If it wasn't nowhere dense then it would contain a nontrivial open interval, which does contradict the Baire category theorem: a countable union of nowhere dense sets has empty interior.