# Is the image of a Borel subset of $[0,1]$ under a differentiable map still a Borel set?

Tags: real-analysis

Let $f:[0,1]\to[0,1]$ be a continuous function such that its derivative $f'$ exists on $(0,1)$. Inspired by [a similar question of myself here](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/413072/46120), I want to ask:

> If $E\subset[0,1]$ is a Borel set, is $f(E)$ still a Borel set?

---

**Remark:**

1. It is known that $f$ maps sets of Lebesgue measure zero to sets of Lebesgue measure zero(for example, one may refer to [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/59105/46120)), so it follows easily that $f$ maps Lebesgue measurable sets to Lebesgue measurable sets.
2. Even if $f$ is assumed to be $C^1$, the answer is unclear to me.
3. As pointed by George Lowther in a comment in [the same post](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/59105/46120), it is well known that for the natural projection $p:\mathbb R^2\to \mathbb R$, $p(x,y)=x$, which is clearly real analytic, the image of  a Borel set of $\mathbb R^2$ under $p$ may not be a Borel set in $\mathbb R$. More details can be found [here](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/106933/borel-sets-preserved-under-open-maps). It follows that for a high dimensional analog of the question, i.e. for $f:[0,1]^n\to\mathbb R^m$, $n\ge 2$, even when $f$ is real analytic, the answer is **negative**.

---

Any hint or suggestion is appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: It's worth noting that the statement is false if $f$ is merely assumed to be continuous. For example, take $f=\pi\circ g$ where $g\colon[0,1]\to[0,1]^2$ is a space filling curve and $\pi\colon[0,1]^2\to[0,1]$ is the projection. Then, taking any Borel $S\subset[0,1]^2$ with $\pi(S)$ not Borel, $E=g^{-1}(S)$ gives a Borel set whose image under $f$ is not Borel.

Comment: @GeorgeLowther: Yes, it's an excellent remark. Thank you!

Answer (score 36, accepted):

Even for $C^\infty$ functions $f\colon[0,1]\to[0,1]$, it is possible that $f(E)$ is not Borel for some Borel sets $E$.

Starting with the simpler case where $f$ is only required to be continuous, one way to construct a counterexample is to start with a [space filling curve](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Space-filling_curve) $g\colon[0,1]\to[0,1]^2$ whose image is the entire unit square. Then write $f=\pi\circ g$ where $\pi\colon[0,1]^2\to[0,1]$ is the standard projection $\pi(x,y)=x$. It is then a standard fact that there exist Borel sets $F\subset[0,1]^2$ whose projection $\pi(F)$ is not Borel. In fact, the projections of Borel sets are precisely the [analytic](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Analytic_set) sets, and there do exist analytic sets which are not Borel. Then, taking $E=g^{-1}(F)$, this is Borel set whose image under $f$ is the non-Borel set $\pi(F)$.

Now, moving on to the differentiable - and, even, smooth - case, the first thing to note is that the image of a differentiable function $g\colon[0,1]\to[0,1]^2$ must have zero Lebesgue measure, so cannot fill the unit square. However, this is not necessary. All we need is that the image of $g$ contains $C^2$ for some closed uncountable set $C\subset[0,1]$ (e.g., a [Cantor set](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cantor_set)). Such sets are always Borel isomorphic to the interval $[0,1]$ (as are all uncountable [Polish spaces](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polish_space)). So, we can procede as above and let $E=g^{-1}(F)$ where $F\subset C^2$ is Borel such that $\pi(F)$ is not Borel.

So, it remains to find a closed uncountable $C\subset[0,1]$ and smooth $g\colon[0,1]\to[0,1]^2$ containing $C^2$ in its image. I will choose $C$ to be a 'thin Cantor set'. By this, I mean that $C$ is constructed in the same way as the [fat Cantor set](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Smith-Volterra-Cantor_Set), except we remove larger and larger proportions of the set at each stage of the construction instead of smaller and smaller proportions. Choose a sequence $\alpha_0,\alpha_1,\ldots\in(0,1/2)$ with $\alpha_n\to0$ as $n\to\infty$. Then define a sequence of closed sets as follows. Let $C_0=[0,1]$. For each $n\ge0$, once $C_n$ has been chosen (and is a finite union of disjoint closed intervals), we remove the centre $1-2\alpha_n$ proportion of each interval in $C_n$ to obtain $C_{n+1}$. Then, $C=\bigcap_nC_n$. Equivalently, $C$ is the set of points which can be written as
$$
(1-\alpha_0)x_0+\alpha_0(1-\alpha_1)x_1+\alpha_0\alpha_1(1-\alpha_2)x_2+\alpha_0\alpha_1\alpha_2(1-\alpha_3)x_3+\cdots
$$
for $x_0,x_1,\ldots\in\lbrace0,1\rbrace$. Note that if we had $\alpha_0=\alpha_1=\cdots=1/3$ then this is the usual Cantor middle thirds set.

Now, I'll describe the function $g$. This will be done in an inductive fashion using self-similarity. We can set $g=g_0$ where, for each $n\ge0$, $g_n\colon[0,1]\to[0,1]^2$ contains scaled and maybe reflected copies of another such map $g_{n+1}$ in each of the four corner sections $[0,\alpha_n]^2$, $[0,\alpha_n]\times[1-\alpha_n,1]$, $[1-\alpha_n,1]^2$, $[1-\alpha_n,1]\times[0,\alpha_n]$ of the unit square, and follows straight lines in between these regions. This is as in the image below.

[image: smooth curve covering a thin Cantor dust]

Let $\theta\colon[0,1]\to[0,1]$ be a smooth function with $\theta(0)=0$, $\theta(1)=1$ and such that its derivatives all vanish at the endpoints. For example, $\theta(x)$ could be taken to be the integral of $\exp(-1/(x(1-x)))$ appropriately scaled. Then, to be precise, we define $g=g_0$ where $g_n=(g_{n,1},g_{n,2})\colon[0,1]\to[0,1]^2$ are defined inductively by
$$
g_n(x)=\begin{cases}
\alpha_n(g_{n+1,2}(7x),g_{n+1,1}(7x))&{\rm if\ } 0\le x\le 1/7,\\[.3em]
(0,\alpha_n+(1-2\alpha_n)\theta(7x-1))&{\rm if\ } 1/7 < x < 2/7,\\[.3em]
\alpha_n(g_{n+1,1}(7x-2),g_{n+1,2}(7x-2)-1)+(0,1)&{\rm if\ } 2/7\le x\le 3/7,\\[.3em]
(\alpha_n+(1-2\alpha_n)\theta(7x-3),1-\alpha_n)&{\rm if\ } 3/7 < x < 4/7,\\[.3em]
\alpha_n(g_{n+1,1}(7x-4)-1,g_{n+1,2}(7x-4)-1)+(1,1)&{\rm if\ } 4/7 \le x \le 5/7,\\[.3em]
(1,1-\alpha_n-(1-2\alpha_n)\theta(7x-5))&{\rm if\ } 5/7 < x < 6/7,\\[.3em]
\alpha_n(-g_{n+1,2}(7x-6),1-g_{n+1,1}(7x-6))+(1,0)&{\rm if\ } 6/7 \le x \le 1.
\end{cases}
$$
This does uniquely define $g$. Note that if $\tilde g_n$ was any other sequence of functions to the unit square satisfying the same recurrence equations, then we have $\lVert\tilde g_n - g_n\rVert=\alpha_n\lVert\tilde g_{n+1} - g_{n+1}\rVert$, where $\lVert\cdot\rVert$ is the supremum norm. Also, as they both map into the unit square, $\lVert \tilde g_n-g_n\rVert\le\sqrt{2}$. Putting these together,
$$
\lVert\tilde g_n-g_n\rVert\le\alpha_n\alpha_{n+1}\cdots\alpha_{n+r-1}\sqrt{2}
$$
for all $r\ge0$. Letting $r$ go to infinity shows that $\tilde g_n=g_n$.

We can also construct a sequence of smooth approximations to $g$. For each $N\ge0$ define a map $g_N^{(N)}(x)=(\theta(x),0)$. Then, inductively define $g_{N-1}^{(N)},g_{N-2}^{(N)},\ldots,g_0^{(N)}$ using the recurrence equation above. Note that, at each step, $g^{(N)}_n$ is a smooth function with $g^{(N)}_n(0)=(0,0)$ and $g^{(N)}_n(1)=(1,0)$, and whose derivatives vanish to all orders at the end points. Next, using $D^rg$ to represent the r'th order derivatives of a function $g$, we have
$$
\lVert D^rg_n^{(N)}\rVert=7^r\max\left(\alpha_n\lVert D^rg_{n+1}^{(N)}\rVert,(1-2\alpha_n)\lVert D^r\theta\rVert\right)
$$
for all $r\ge1$. From this, we can see that $\lVert D^rg_n^{(N)}\rVert$ is bounded by $(7^r\alpha_n)\cdots(7^r\alpha_{n+k-1})7^r\lVert D^r\theta\rVert$ for some $k\ge0$. As we chose $\alpha_n$ to be tending to zero, this is bounded by some constant $L_r$ independently of $n,k$. Next, for any natural numbers $n < M\le N$, the recurrence equation gives
$$
\begin{align}
\lVert D^rg_n^{(M)}-D^rg_n^{(N)}\rVert &= 7^r\alpha_n\lVert D^rg_{n+1}^{(M)}-D^rg_{n+1}^{(N)}\rVert\cr
&=(7^r\alpha_n)(7^r\alpha_{n+1})\cdots(7^r\alpha_{M-1})\lVert D^rg_M^{(M)}-D^rg_M^{(N)}\rVert\cr
&\le(7^r\alpha_n)(7^r\alpha_{n+1})\cdots(7^r\alpha_{M-1})2L_r
\end{align}
$$
Again since we chose $\alpha_n$ tending to zero, this shows that $\lVert D^rg_n^{(M)}-D^rg_n^{(N)}\rVert$ tends to zero as $M,N$ go to infinity. Therefore, the sequence of functions $g_n^{(N)}$ converges uniformly as $N\to\infty$, along with its derivatives to all orders. The limit, $g_n$, satisfies the defining recurrence equations above. So, $g$ is infinitely differentiable.

Note, finally, that by choosing $x=x_0/7+x_1/7^2+x_2/7^3+\cdots$ for appropriate $x_n\in\lbrace0,2,4,6\rbrace$ we can find $x$ so that $g(x)$ is equal to any desired element of $C^2$.

Comment: Dear George Lowther, your answer is wonderful and I am really grateful for your help.

Comment: @Landscape: I made those changes, and added a bit more detail (I'll also change my later $f$'s to $g$'s to be consistent with the opening paragraphs).

Comment: Now It looks perfect to me! Thank you sincerely.

Comment: This is a heroic feat of exposition.

Comment: @Ilya: Many thanks for the unexpected bounty!