# Does a measurable function map every measurable set to a measurable set in its image?

Tags: measure-theory, measurable-functions

So consider a measurable function $f: (X, \mathcal{F}) \rightarrow (Y, \mathcal{G})$.
The measurablility tells me that the pre-image of every measurable set $A\in \mathcal{G}$ is in $\mathcal{F}$, i.e., $f^{-1}(A)\in\mathcal{F}$.
My question is now: If I start with some set $B\in\mathcal{F}$, is that set alwlays mapped to a set in $\mathcal{G}$, i.e., if $f(B)\in\mathcal{G}$ for every $B\in\mathcal{F}$?

Personally, I would say this is not the case, because I dont see that there would be a contradiction with the Def of measurability if $f(B)$ was mapped to a subset of $Y$ that is not in $\mathcal{F}$.

Comment: There are very easy counter-examples. Take $\mathcal G=\{\emptyset,Y\}$ and $f$ to be a constant function.

Comment: For the interesting case $(X,\mathcal F)=(Y,\mathcal G)=(\Bbb R,\mathcal B(\Bbb R))$, we have $C^\infty$ functions that do not send all Borel sets to Borel sets. https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/415759/is-the-image-of-a-borel-subset-of-0-1-under-a-differentiable-map-still-a-bor?rq=1

Comment: Here is an easy example of a measurable function $f:(\Bbb R,\text{Lebesgue})\to (\Bbb R,\mathcal B(\Bbb R))$ with non-measurable (hence non-Borel) image. https://mathoverflow.net/questions/298220/measurable-functions-with-non-measurable-image

If you look closely, $f$ is actually measurable $(\Bbb R,\text{Lebesgue})\to(\Bbb R,\text{Lebesgue})$.

Comment: thanks for your answers!

Comment: @geetha290krm is your counter example still a counter example if also $\mathcal{F}$ consists only of the empty set and $X$?

Comment: No, it is not. But you just need one other set in $\mathbb F$. Also, $Y$ should be a singleton.