# $m(E)=0$ then $m(\lbrace x^2 : x\in E\rbrace$?

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, measure-theory, lebesgue-measure

Let E be a subset of $\mathbb{R}$ with lebesgue measure zero. How can I prove that $\lbrace x^2 : x\in E\rbrace$ also has lebesgue measure zero?

---

Let $\epsilon>0$, I should find a cover of $\lbrace x^2 : x\in E\rbrace$ with total length at most $\epsilon$. since $m(E)=0$ so there exists a countable collection of intervals $\{ (a_k, b_k)\}$ such that $\sum b_k-a_k<\epsilon$. Then what is the next step? How can I find a cover for $\lbrace x^2 : x\in E\rbrace$?  If without loss of generality we think that $E\subset \mathbb{R}^+$ then $\bigcup (a_k^2, b_k^2)$ is a cover for $\lbrace x^2 : x\in E\rbrace$. But how to prove $\sum b_k^2-a_k^2<\epsilon$?

Comment: Use that a set has Lebesgue measure zero if it can be covered by countably many intervals of total length at most $\epsilon$ for each $\epsilon>0$.

Comment: @MichaelGreinecker: Thank you.Let $\epsilon>0$, I should find a cover of $\lbrace x^2 : x\in E\rbrace$ with total lenght at most $\epsilon$. since $m(E)=0$ so there exists a countable collection of intervals $\lbrace (a_k, b_k)\rbrace$ such that $\sum b_k-a_k<\epsilon$. Then what is the next step? How can I find a cover for $\lbrace x^2 : x\in E\rbrace$?

Comment: If without loss of generality we think that $E\subset \mathbb{R}^+$ then $\bigcup (a_k^2, b_k^2)$ is a cover for $\lbrace x^2 : x\in E\rbrace$. But How to prove $\sum b_k^2-a_k^2<\epsilon$?

Comment: You could try using [this](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/59105/is-the-image-of-a-null-set-under-a-differentiable-map-always-null?lq=1).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let $f(x)=x^2$. If $I$ is an interval, then $f(I)$ is also an interval, and if $I=(a,b)$, then $f(I)$ is one of $(a^2,b^2)$, $(b^2,a^2)$, $[0,a^2)$ and $[0,b^2)$, the latter two cases occurring only if $a$ and $b$ are of opposite sign. Suppose now that $b-a<1$. If $a<0<b$, then $-1<a$ and $b<1$, so $b^2<b$, $a^2<-a$, and the latter two intervals have length strictly smaller than $b-a$. If $I\subseteq[-M,M]$ and $a$ and $b$ have the same sign, then $|b^2-a^2|=|b+a||b-a|\le 2M|b-a|$.

Let now $E$ be a set of measure $0$. Since $E=\bigcup_n E\cap (-n,n)$, we may assume that $E$ is bounded: $\{x^2\mid x\in E\}$ will not be null iff $\{x^2\mid x\in E\cap(-n,n)\}$ is not null for some $n$. Let $M\ge 1$ be a bound for $E$, that is, $E\subseteq [-M,M]$, and let's further assume that $-M,M\notin E$. Since $E$ has measure $0$, for any $\epsilon>0$ we can cover $E$ with intervals whose lengths add up at most to $\min\{1/2,\epsilon/2M\}$. We may also assume that all these intervals are also contained in $[M,M]$, and since the sum of their lengths is at most $1/2$, they all have length less than $1$. It follows from the previous paragraph that if $I$ is any of these intervals, then $f(I)$ has length at most $2M$ times the length of $I$. Note that the $f(I)$ cover $f(E)$, and their lengths add up to at most $2m(\epsilon/2M)=\epsilon$. It follows that $f(E)$ also has measure zero.

(There is a small technical detail, depending on whether one insists that the intervals that cover are open. In that case, we can remove from each $f(I)$ its endpoints if necessary. This leaves at most countably many points of $f(E)$ uncovered, but this is irrelevant, since countable sets are null.)

Note that the same argument shows that if $f$ is any differentiable function whose derivative is bounded on bounded sets, then $f(E)$ is null for any null set $E$: All we need to do to adapt the argument is to use the mean value theorem to note that there is a constant $K$ (expressible in terms of $M$ and $B$, where $B$ is a bound for $f$ in $[-M,M]$) such that for any interval $I\subseteq [-M,M]$, we have that the length of $f(I)$ is at most $K$ times the length of $I$. A bit more work shows that the assumption on boundedness of the derivative can be eliminated. These are special cases of results that go back to [Luzin](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nikolai_Luzin), who investigated the question of when a function $f$ maps null sets to null sets, and said that $f$ had [property (N)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Luzin_N_property) if that was the case.

Comment: Andres: Thank you so much. I just don't understand why we can assume that $E$ is bounded?

Comment: Write $E=E_1\cup E_2\cup E_3\cup\dots$ where $E_i=E\cap(-i,i)$, so each $E_i$ is bounded. Then $f(E)=f(E_1)\cup f(E_2)\cup\dots$ We argued that when $E$ is bounded, then $f(E)$ has measure $0$. It follows that $f(E_1)$ has measure $0$, since $E_1$ is bounded. Similarly, $f(E_2)$ has measure zero, since $E_2$ is bounded, etc. Since $f(E)$ is the union of countably many null sets, it is null as well.